# Cant't define structure in main in c++

Tags: c++, struct, structure

Cant't define structure in main in c++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    struct d
    {
        char name[20];
        int age;

    };
    struct d s,f;
    s = { "agent smith" , 17 };

    cout << s.name << " is 17 year old\n";
    return 0;
}
```

whenever I compile My code I get Following error:-

```
$ g++ test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:25:27: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘main()::d’ and ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’)
  s = { "agent smith" , 17 };
                           ^
test.cpp:18:9: note: candidate: constexpr main()::d& main()::d::operator=(const main()::d&)
  struct d
         ^
test.cpp:18:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const main()::d&’
test.cpp:18:9: note: candidate: constexpr main()::d& main()::d::operator=(main()::d&&)
test.cpp:18:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘main()::d&&’
```

What is wrong in my code ? I am going as the books says(c++ primer Plus 6thED)

Comment: FYI this compiles with [clang 3.9.1 -std=c++11.](https://godbolt.org/g/SR3ny4) It does *not* compile with g++ no matter which version I tried.

Comment: @WhozCraig You are right .This is only not compiling in g++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to explicit the constructor:

```
s = d{ "agent smith" , 17 };
```

or define with explicit [initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

```
d s{"agent smith", 17};
```

(assuming [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), so with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) -preferably at least GCC 6- compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g`)

PS. Don't bother learning something older than C++11. Notice that C++17 has been recently [approved](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Cpp17-Formal-Go) (september 2017), but is too young today to have mature implementations.

Comment: This would indeed seem the most viable solution.

Comment: Is this new c++ standard ?? Why it compiles in other compilers but not in g++(gcc) ??

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? What C++ standard are you expecting?

Comment: So is this new c++11 standard ?? my books is the latest one (c++ primer plus 6TH EDITION )

Comment: The latest standard is [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) recently [approved](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Cpp17-Formal-Go). But you won't find in september 2017 many implementations of it. So stick to C++11 or C++14

Comment: But did you pass the `-std=c++11` option to `g++` ?

Comment: no. But I did now. And same errors are coming. But i am confuse Now.Should stop learning from this book ??

Comment: Learn C++11 at least. I don't know your book. Stroustrup has written a good [book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) and is the inventor of C++

Answer (score 1):

I think you're problem is that you're trying to initialize with the 'initializer list' after you already defined your variables.

This should work:

```
 d s = { "agent smith", 17 };
 d f = { "agent john",  19 };
```

Answer (score -1):

The working version of this program:

1. As you use extended initializer (one with `{}`) use `-std=c++11` compilation option
2. use `->` to call structure's fields
3. free memory after using structure (`delete s`)
4. use `string` for string field or use array of `char` appropriately ("something" is a string)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

    struct d
    {
        string name;
        int age;
    };

int main()
{
    d *s = new d{ "agent smith" , 17 };
    cout << s->name << " is 17 year old\n";
    delete s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new` and `delete` are not required. The heap allocation is pointless.

Comment: Are you abhor the  heap allocation that much as to give emotionally biased  "-1" for correctly working code ?


Otherwise would you mind  providing us with a solid proof based on C++11 Standards that prohibit using heap memory allocation to structures.
( ISO/IEC 9899:2011, latest draft counts due to free access to it)

Comment: I did not say it was prohibited. It's entirely unnecessary here, and gives people the impression that this is how we write modern C++ code. We don't use heap allocations when we don't need them, and when we do need them, we use unique_ptr and friends. `new` and `delete` are *poor style* in cases like this.

Comment: Note also that "correctly working" does not imply "good."  Code that works well might use constructs known to be harmful, and in this case it's particularly bad to suggest to a new C++ programmer that a heap allocation is a good idea in this case. It's even worse to suggest using raw `new`/`delete` to a new programmer.